# Existence of a "generic enough" lattice point interior to a lattice triangle

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, euclidean-geometry, triangulations

Let $T$ be a lattice triangle in $\Bbb R^2$ (i.e. the convex hull of three noncolinear points in $\Bbb Z^2$), and assume it has at least one interior lattice point. Is it always possible to find a point $p\in \operatorname{interior}(T)\cap \Bbb Z^2$ satisfying the following condition:

(*) $\operatorname{conv}(p,v)\cap \Bbb Z^2 = \{p,v\}$ for every vertex $v\in T$, where $\operatorname{conv}$ is convex hull.

For example: In this picture:

[image: good]

$p=D$ works, whereas in this picture:

[image]

$p=D$ does not work because the line segment $DC$ passes through $E$.

**Edit:** In light of fedja's counterexample (the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(3,2)$, and $(1,3)$, and at their suggestion, I'm modifying the question to ask if (*) holds when $T$ contains "sufficiently many" points in the interior.

Comment: It looks to me like your definition of $T$ is a bit ambiguous, as it first refers to the entire triangle (with interior), but later (possibly) refers to only the three vertices of it.

Comment: @MarcusM I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: When you say $p \in T \cap \mathbb{Z}^2$, it looks like you mean for $T$ to include the interior of the triangle; however, your condition for $p$ that you seek is more ambiguous.  It says $\text{conv}(p,v) = \{p,v\}$ for all $v \in T$, however in your image you only tested in for $v$ being the extreme points (i.e. the three vertices) of the triangle.  Is that the condition that you seek?

Comment: @MarcusM I didn't even think about that! I've made a clarification of what I mean. I also clarified that I want p to be in the interior of T.

Comment: How about (0,0), (3,2),(1,3) for the vertices of $T$?

Comment: @fedja If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @AviSteiner If your curiosity stops here, I will, though I believe that life will be more interesting if we modify the question by changing the assumptions to "$T$ contains sufficiently many points in the interior". After all, small size counterexamples in such questions are usually not very exciting or meaningful.

Comment: @fedja hm that would be quite intersecting. I’ll modify the question

Comment: There are general visibility results by Adikhari which may be a start on this.  Essentially, if an integer interval is large enough, it contains an integer coprime to a given integer N, and this has implications to your problem.  Search for work of Granville in this area too.  Gerhard "Will Help Look For Forest" Paseman, 2018.12.12.